# what's the diff between rpm -U and rpm -F

Tags: linux, rpm

Bit confused.

what's the diff between `rpm -U` and `rpm -F`

man pages say -U upgrade package

> -F, --freshen=+     upgrade package(s) if already installed

Answer (score 9):

Compare

```
   rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   This  upgrades  or  installs the package currently installed to a newer
   version.  This is the same as install, except all other  version(s)  of
   the package are removed after the new package is installed.
```

to

```
   rpm {-F|--freshen} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

   This  will upgrade packages, but only ones for which an earlier version
   is installed.
```

Comment: Key words: **only ones for which an earlier version is installed.**